# How can I discover/control the level of internal buffering in a C++ fstream?

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream

Say I do this (a contrived example):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream ifs(argv[1]);

    char ch;
    while(ifs.read(&ch, 1)) {
        cout << ch;
    }
}
```

I assume(hope) that the iostream library does some internal buffering here and doesn't turn this into gazillions of one-byte file-read operations at the OS level.

Is there a way of:

**a)** Finding out the size of ifstream's internal buffer?

**b)** Changing the size of ifstream's internal buffer?

I'm writing a file filter that needs to read multi-gigabyte files in small chunks and I'd like to experiment with different buffer sizes to see if it affects performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ios::rdbuf()` to get a pointer to a `streambuf` object. This object represents the internal buffer for the stream.

You can call `streambuf::pubsetbuf(char * s, streamsize n)` to set a new internal buffer with a given size.

See [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/pubsetbuf.html) for more details.

**edit:** Here is how it would look in your case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argCount, char ** argList[])
{
    ifstream inStream(argList[1]);

    char myBuffer [512];
    inStream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(myBuffer, sizeof(myBuffer));

    char ch;
    while(inStream.read(&ch, 1))
    {
        cout << ch;
    }
}
```

**edit:** as pointed out by [litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/litb), the actual behavior of `streambuf::pubsetbuf` is "implementation-defined".

If you really want to play around with the buffers, you may have to roll your own buffering class that inherits from `streambuf`.

Comment: Isn't it better to use 'sizeof(myBuffer)' in the call to pubsetbug?

Comment: i've looked it up in the standard, because i wasn't aware what pubsetbuf does, and it says it is implementation-defined what it does. except that pubsetbuf(0, 0) before any I/O will disable buffering

Comment: @litb: Lovely! From now on, I'm going to label all of my interfaces as "implementation-defined". That way, I won't have to actually do any work :)